# How to get value of textview to two different activites in android through intent and bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

How to get value of textview to two different activites in android through intent and bundle
Please tell me..
My code is as below:

**Activity1.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("title",ed1.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity2.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String title = bundle.getString("title");
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.projectTitle);
tv.setText(title);
bundle.putString("tit",title);
```

**Activity3.java**
B

```
undle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Projecttitle);
tv.setText(til);
```

its working well in activity1 and activity2 but not between activity2 and activity3

Comment: Post the code of Activity 2 which starts activity 3. And you are putting string as "tit" in bundle in Activity 2. Are you sure you are fetching it as "tit", and not "til"?

Comment: Did you set the `intent.putExtras(bundle);` before starting `Activity3`

Comment: like you used intent for Activity2 from Activity1, you need to do the same for Activity2 and 3.

Comment: @jims Hello jims, If my answer is helping you then please accept it so it will help others also.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya-its working bro...tnx...but m new to stackoverflow..tell me how to xcept? :o

Answer (score 2):

Your Code is not working because you are not get string value from bundle in activity3.java,

Update your below code in activity2.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("title",tv.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

And Update your below code in `onCreate()` method of Activity3.java

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String til = bundle.getString("title");
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Projecttitle);
tv.setText(til);
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Dipak-bro to sccept answer is clicking on "yes" on "was this post useful to you?"

Comment: @jims For accept the answer, click on right icon on left side of my answer.

Comment: @jims Hello jims, where are you from?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the data to intent in order to set the data from the second activity to third activity. If you are unable to get still, post the code where you are actually adding data to the intent in your second activity and where you get the data in the third activity.

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);

intent.putExtra("title",title)
startActivity(intent);
```

Get the value in the third activity:

```
String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

**Note:** When your title is not changed in 2nd activity, you don't need to do this step like `editText.getText().toString();` in the putextra method.